# C++: Getting hex unexpectedly when printing array

Tags: c++, hex, cout

I am declaring an array using new

```
int *a = NULL;
a = new int[10];

a[0] = 23;
a[1] = 43;
a[2] = 45;
a[3] = 76;
a[4] = 34;
a[5] = 85;
a[6] = 34;
a[7] = 97;
a[8] = 45;
a[9] = 22;

PrintElements(a, 10);

void PrintElements(int * array, int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cout << endl << array[i];
    }
}
```

Now when I print the values I am getting these values

```
17
2b
2d
4c
22
55
22
61
2d
16
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong...?
On the other hand when I dont use new & initialize array without it everything works fine.

Comment: I think someone should edit the title to reflect the true nature of the problem. This is kind of misleading and would probably be unhelpful for someone Googling for dynamic arrays in C++. (in fact it's the 3rd hit on Google right now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have written a std::hex to the cout at some point; that will remain in effect until overridden.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt have anything to do with the static or dynamic allocation of the array.

The numbers are printed as Hexadecimal values and not decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
std::cout << dec << //all your stuff here
```

It's still set in hex mode.

Answer (score 1):

> 17 2b 2d 4c 22 55 22 61 2d 16

These are obviously hexadecimal numbers. If you print them as decimals you get 23, 43, etc. IOW, exactly the numbers that you have put into the array. Some piece of your code executed prior to your `PrintElements()` apparently changes the formatting to output hexadecimal numbers.